# Flutter TextFormField FilteringTextInputFormatter remove leading zero

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, validation, textformfield

I'm trying to implement an inputfield of number with 3 rules:

1. Number can range from -3000 ~ 3000, including zero
2. Can't have/replace leading zeros (ex. 0012 would be converted to 12)
3. -0 will be replaced to 0

So for example:

- 00444: fail (automatically replaced to 444 to be success)
- -2442: success
- 0: success
- -0: fail (automatically replaced to 0 to be success)
- -03000: fail (automatically replaced to -3000 to be success)

Here is what I have implemented so far:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('^-?[1-9]')),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('-0'), replacementString: '0'),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('^0+')),
  ],
),
```

I have managed to limit number range to -3000 ~ 3000 to work (not in above code),
and with RegEx implemented, managed to format both positive and negative numbers.
Also by using `FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'-0'), replacementString: '0')`, I was able to replace -0 to 0.

The problem is that when the input contains leading zero, above code (`FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('^0+')),`) would not allow / remove leading zero, but having 0 as only input would not work.

Is there a way to achieve what I intended?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure theres a way...consider creating your own custom TextInputFormatter that suit you use cases

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with dart/flutter, but I did see that Dart regular expressions have the same syntax and semantics as JavaScript regular expressions. Therefor I would like to suggest the following:

```
^(-(?!0+$))?-?0*([12]?\d{1,3}|3000)$
```

Replace this with `$1$2`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4w2JYi/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(-(?!0+$))?` - A 1st optional capture group to capture the leading hyphen only if not only trailing zero's  before end-line anchor;
- `-?0*` - Match an optional hyphen and 0+ (Greedy) leading zero's;
- `([12]?\d{1,3}|3000)` - A 2nd capture group to match any digit ranging -3000~3000;
- `$` - End-line anchor.